# firewalld apply interface zone after ipset zone match

Tags: firewalld, ipset, firewalld-zone

I have a firewalld setup with two zones.

One zone, `some-ips-allowed`, is used to permit traffic from specific IP networks on some ports:

```
some-ips-allowed (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources: ipset:some-ip-set
  services:
  ports: 22/tcp 80/tcp 443/tcp
  ...
```

The `some-ip-set` contains some networks, say, `10.0.0.0/8`.

Another zone has some interfaces assigned (whitelisted, due to `target: ACCEPT`):

```
something-trusted (active)
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: eth123
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  ...
```

The interface, `eth123`, has IP in the same network: `10.0.0.1`.

Now the tricky case: if I try to access the machine via interface `eth123` on port ex. `123`, I get rejected. This is because of the priorities: firewalld sets up nftables so that ipsets are handled before interfaces, and zone `some-ips-allowed` doesn't permit port `123`.

Here's the excerpt from `nft list ruleset`, note the `goto` directive:

```
chain filter_INPUT_ZONES {
    ip saddr @some-ip-set goto filter_IN_some-ip-set
    iifname "eth123" goto filter_IN_something-trusted
    ...
```

Shortly speaking, the logic is that if connection's IP matches, the ipset zone is used, and that's it.

What I want to achieve is: If the connection's IP matches, and it isn't explicitly handled, then it would be processed the next matching zone (an interface zone).

Is this doable in firewalld, preferrably without meddling with `nft` commands directly?

**Edit:**
According to this: https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Jumping_to_chain, I can see I to have a `jump` instead of `goto` in nft rules.

Again, can this be done with `firewall-cmd`-level commands?
If not, is it safe (i.e. will it not cause unpredictable conflicts and side effect) to use `nft` commands directly, even though the rest of the configuration is managed by `firewall-cmd`?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's not possible to do just this using `firewall-cmd`.

However, the desired effect can be obtained using firewalld's *Policies* instead of *Zones*.

Consider the following Policy:

```
some-ips-allowed-policy (active)
  priority: -1
  target: CONTINUE
  ingress-zones: ANY
  egress-zones: HOST
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:
        rule family="ipv4" source ipset="some-ip-set" port port="22" protocol="tcp" accept
```

It will be applied to all incoming traffic (thanks to `ANY` and `HOST` ingress / egress zones), and will `accept` connections from IPs in the provided ipset.

Now, if the policy doesn't match the IPs, it will simply go on to process the zones (note the `CONTINUE` target). `nft` shows that policies generate `jump` statements - just what was needed.

Additionally, using the `priority` setting, it can be easily controlled whether a policy is applied before or after processing of the zones.